# Access to a file upload in gridView footer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is my part of code for the grid view

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gridViewCourse" 
            runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            onrowcancelingedit="gridViewCourse_RowCancelingEdit" 
            onrowdeleting="gridViewCourse_RowDeleting" onrowediting="gridViewCourse_RowEditing" 
            onrowupdating="gridViewCourse_RowUpdating" 
            onrowcommand="gridViewCourse_RowCommand" 
            datakeynames="CourseId"

            ShowFooter="True">
         .....

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fichier">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadFichier" CssClass="upload" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Fichier") %>'/>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFichier" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Fichier") %>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadFichier" CssClass="upload" runat="server"  />

                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFichier" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUploadFichier" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>
                    </FooterTemplate>

        ....
```

This my method "onrowcommand="gridViewCourse_RowCommand""

```
        Protected Sub gridViewCourse_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew") Then
        Dim txtId As TextBox = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrId"), TextBox)
        Dim txtCours As TextBox = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrCours"), TextBox)
        Dim txtPrix As TextBox = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrPrix"), TextBox)
        Dim txtTutor As TextBox = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrTuteur"), TextBox)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(((("insert into Courses(CourseID,CourseName,Price,Tutor) values('" + txtId.Text & "','") + txtCours.Text & "','") + txtPrix.Text & "','") + txtTutor.Text & "')", con)
        Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        If result = 1 Then
            BindCoursesDetails()
            lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green
            lblresult.Text = " Details inserted successfully"
        Else
            lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Red
            lblresult.Text = " Details not inserted"


        End If
    End If

    Dim upload As FileUpload = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FindControl("FileUploadFichier"), FileUpload)

    upload.SaveAs((Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath & "/CoursesFiles/" & Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName))))
End Sub
```

The problem is The cast to upload (As FileUpload) contain nothing after...
The others  are good and effective...

How I can acces to the FileUpload1 and  save it ?

Thanks Frank

Comment: Is this in an UpdatePanel perchance?

Comment: No its in a grid view footer my control file upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         Protected Sub gridViewCourse_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
If e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew") Then
    Dim txtId As TextBox = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrId"), TextBox)
    Dim txtCours As TextBox = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrCours"), TextBox)
    Dim txtPrix As TextBox = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrPrix"), TextBox)
    Dim txtTutor As TextBox = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrTuteur"), TextBox)

Dim upload As FileUpload = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FindControl("FileUploadFichier"), FileUpload)

upload.SaveAs((Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath & "/CoursesFiles/" & Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName))))
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(((("insert into Courses(CourseID,CourseName,Price,Tutor) values('" + txtId.Text & "','") + txtCours.Text & "','") + txtPrix.Text & "','") + txtTutor.Text & "')", con)
    Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    If result = 1 Then
        BindCoursesDetails()
        lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green
        lblresult.Text = " Details inserted successfully"
    Else
        lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblresult.Text = " Details not inserted"


    End If
End If
```

End Sub

I have to put the cast before BindCoursesDetails()

Answer (score 0):

You're using two fileupload controls with the same id, try different IDs

and replace this line

```
     Dim upload As FileUpload = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FindControl("FileUploadFichier"), FileUpload)
```

with this one

```
  Dim upload As FileUpload = DirectCast(gridViewCourse.FooterRow.FindControl("FileUploadFichier"), FileUpload)
```

Comment: Still have nothing in the upload, File name = "" and length = 0